# Creating an Integrity verification processes

Tags: mysql, data-integrity, integrity

I am trying to create a data verification system for a platform I am trying to make. I have data in files and in database (mysql). what I want is to create a general resource type agnostic system that lets me verify the integrity of my data.

I know that I can use hash functions in some way for verification, but I am asking for a bigger idea that involves more than just hashing the files and verifying the hash afterwards.

any ideas on how to make such system?

Comment: Yes. Use hashes. That's their **purpose**. What in the world made you think there's something "else" or "bigger idea"?

Comment: @N.B. I am relatively new to this. so I thought there would be something else, at least , better structured and standardized.

Comment: Ok, you're new. What does it mean when you type *better structured* or *standardized*? There's something hashes don't do in your case or what? Hashing algorithms are standardized. There's no better structure than to compare `hash(object 1)` against `hash(object 2)`. It's the most trivial operation in programming. What else do you need? It's literally the easiest possible thing in the world, that's why it was made and that's why it's so beautifully easy to implement.

Comment: What I am thinking is some standard of integrity verification, It can be based on hashing but something more than hashing each file of the database and keeping those hashes somewhere for further verification. I am more asking if those systems do exits.

Comment: So what you're after is basically a service that will tell you `yes` or `no` if you ask it whether two things are identical or not? If yes, then - I don't know of such service. Since it would be for your own platform, it's most likely something you'll have to develop on your own. And if you do, it will use hashing as its engine.